How to change to Font size of eForm input field in ABC.pdf9
I have a fillable pdf that has fillable and non-fillable fields.
I'm able to change the font size for the text that is added to non-fillable fields using following code:
Doc.FontSize = 12;
Doc.AddText(text);

But this does not work for the fillable fields, the font size is not applied:
Field VisitDate = aForm.Form["Date1_af_date"];
VisitDate.Value = aDetails.VisitDate.ToString();

How do I change the font size or convert the field to auto decrease the font?
Edit:
There are two types of fillable fields in my file(from Atom items):
{[DA, (/Helv  0 Tf 0 g)]}
{[DA, (/TiRo 12 Tf 0 g)]}

The ones that are set to 0px are auto resizable and the ones set 12px are not. How can I update this setting?

@KJ, after I fill in the file from the code I stamp and flatten it, so no more editable fields are present. Also the file has a mix of autoresizable and not resizable fields. Ideally I would like to update all the fields to autoresize, or at least change the FontSize based on the value lenght.
